# Ruby On Rails 3 and advanced books covering tests

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a ruby on rails developer for almost 1 year.

I begin to know rather good RoR, and I am looking for some advanced books covering the tests(including RSpec and Cucumber).

I'm not looking for beginner's books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 books came to mind, hopefully they help you out:

- [RSpec book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356379)
- [Rails Test Prescription](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356646)
- [Continuous Testing with Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356700)

Comment: your links are backwards on Rails Test Prescription and Continuous Testing with Ruby. =)

Comment: Thanks for your contributions you both ;)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm also learning about Rails as well. =)